# number.length-1 in an array, what does the "-1" stands for

Tags: arrays, sorting

I am very new to Java. I got this from a website and it does bubblesort. I wonder why is there "-1" after the "number.length". I just don't quite get it. Grateful if anyone could help.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Bubblesort {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] number = {5,16,4,32,30};

    int j;
    boolean flag = true;   // set flag to true to begin first pass
    int temp;   //holding variable

    while ( flag )
    {
          flag= false;    //set flag to false awaiting a possible swap
          for( j=0;  j <number.length-1;  j++ )
          {
                 if ( number[ j ] > number[j+1] )   // change to > for ascending sort
                 {
                         temp = number[ j ];                //swap elements
                         number[ j ] = number[ j+1 ];
                         number[ j+1 ] = temp;
                        flag = true;              //shows a swap occurred
                }
          }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString( number ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are "zero-based", meaning that the first item is in location number zero (0).

If you have 5 items, then this is what it looks like: `Slot: [0] [1] [2] [3] [4]`, so you start with zero and go to length (5) minus one.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, but it doesn't explain why it's used in the question. `for (j=0;j<number.length;j++)` is the correct way to iterate through an array. You missed the part where `j+1` is used as an index.

Comment: @Tim: I guess that just depends on how you interpreted the OP question.

Comment: I disagree. The only reason the `-1` is needed is because `j+1` is used as an index, which you didn't mention but others did.

Comment: I agree to disagree. Which is why I am not editing my answer. There are sufficient answers that go above and beyond the scope of the question (in my opinion). I'll let my answer talk just about the -1. :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question directly, `number.length-1` means "subtract 1 from `number.length`. But to expand slightly about how it's used in the code here:

> ```
> for( j=0;  j <number.length-1;  j++ )
> ```

Normally, to let `j` run from the first valid index to the last, it would look like

```
for (j=0; j<number.length; j++)
```

which lets `j` run from `0` to `number.length - 1`.

However, the algorithm implemented by the code you're asking about subtracts one, because it looks at every element other than the last. For every element, it looks at that element, and the next one. It has to skip the last element, because the last element has no next element.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the other answers don't specifically answer why it's done like that in this algorithm. Yes, `number.length-1` is the last index in the array `number`. But usually, in a `for` loop to go through all elements of an array `j < number.length` would be a good end condition for the loop because it would stop and not execute the loop body once `j` reaches `number.length`.

In this case though, the algorithm later compares `number[ j ]` with `number[ j+1 ]`. That's why the loop needs to stop with a value for `j` one below the last index.

Comment: My answer does explain that :)

Comment: @hvd: Yes, sorry, You published that while I was writing mine.

Comment: Regardless, it's good to have some more attention drawn to it, I think your answer may be better worded than mine.

Answer (score 0):

If an array has length `n` then its first element is at index `0` and its last element is at index `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove 1 from the length of an array to get the last element because arrays are 0-based, but the length is 1-based.

Answer (score 0):

It means literally, the value of `number.length` subtract `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using loop from j = 0

An array of 5 elements have index from 0 to 4

```
int[] arr = new int[5];

arr[0] first element 
arr[1] second element 
arr[2] third element
arr[3] fourth element 
arr[4] fifth element
```

*if you do arr.length() it will give 5*

**so in loop we do 0 to (arr.length() -1)**